# How to 4 side by side image using html to Mobile view vertical and Desktop view Horizontal

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images on my website that I want to display horizontally on desktop and vertically on mobile. (I just started learning HTML so I basically know nothing about coding)

The only thing I could think of was to find a way to set that a number of images will align themselves next to each other as long as there's room for them.

Please tell me if there is any simple way to set this up.

Comment: Have a look at flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `flexbox`. Then add `@media`-queries to address screens with a limited width and change the `flex-direction` there to `column` while the default is `row`.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
}


@media only screen
  and (max-width: 568px) {
    div {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
    

/* for visualisation only */
img {display: block;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.jpg/FF0000">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.jpg/00FF00">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.jpg/0000FF">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.jpg/FFFF00">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the tranform css method to solve this,
"transform: rotate(90deg);". Here is a link to help you more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp
and then add a media query code in the css where the transform property for mobile would be 90deg. Here is a link to help you with the media query: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: rotate is the wrong tool here. Simply task for flexboxes `flex-direction`